# Formating angular datatable before exporting to pdf

Tags: angularjs, pdf, datatables, angular-datatables

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['datatables', 'datatables.buttons']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder) {

  $scope.list = [{
      "eid": "10",
      "type": "1",
      "sales": "20",
      "status": "1"
    }, {
      "eid": "20",
      "type": "2",
      "sales": "40",
      "status": "0"
    }, {
      "eid": "30",
      "type": "1",
      "sales": "20",
      "status": "1"
    }
  ];

  $scope.vm = {};

  $scope.vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('order', [0, 'asc'])
    .withButtons([
      {
        extend: 'collection',
        text: 'Export',
        buttons: [{
            extend: 'copyHtml5',
            title: 'Mylist'
          },
          {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            title: 'My list'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]);

});
```

```css
/* Tooltip container */
.tooltips {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltips .tooltipstext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
 
    /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltips:hover .tooltipstext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://phpflow.com/demo/angular_datatable_demo/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://phpflow.com/demo/angular_datatable_demo/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://phpflow.com/demo/angular_datatable_demo/datatables.bootstrap.css"> 
                      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"> 

      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/dist/plugins/buttons/angular-datatables.buttons.min.js"></script>

      </head>
        <div class="container">
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-column-defs="vm.dtColumnDefs" datatable="ng">
           <thead>
              <tr>
             <th><div class="tooltips">sr <span class="tooltipstext">Poistion</span>
</div>   </th>

          <th>Employee ID</th>
         <th>Type</th>
         <th>sales</th>
          <th>sales_completed</th>

        </thead>
            <tbody>
          
           <tr ng-repeat="data in list">
              <td> {{ $index+1 }} </td>
             
              <td> {{ data.eid }} </td>
              <td> {{ data.type==2? "admin" : "employee"}} </td>
              <td> {{ data.sales }} </td>
            
              <td> 
              
              <span ng-show="{{ data.status }}=='1'"> <div class="tooltips"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i><span class="tooltipstext">Yes</span></div></span>
              <span ng-show="{{ data.status }}=='0'"> <div class="tooltips"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i><span class="tooltipstext">NO</span></div></span>
  
               </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
  
        </table>
        </div>
```

I am using [angular-datatable](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withButtons) plugin, with export buttons.I am trying to export a table as pdf which contains tool tips and glyphicon.I am facing 2 problems while exporting the table.

Problem 1

```
<th>
    <div class="tooltips">sr <span class="tooltipstext">Poistion</span></div> </th>
```

The exported pdf contains the tooltips text

Problem 2

```
<span ng-show="{{ data.status }}=='1'"> <div class="tooltips"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i><span class="tooltipstext">Yes</span></div></span>

<span ng-show="{{ data.status }}=='0'"> <div class="tooltips"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i><span class="tooltipstext">NO</span></div></span>
```

The table is not exporting the glyphicon

How can i format the table so that the tool tips text are excluded and glyphicon is shown in the exported pdf?

Comment: try css media print...

Comment: any link to the resource?

Comment: `@media print {
    .tooltips { 
        display:none;
    }
}`
you can style your classes only for print with @media print...

Comment: in this case @media print not working!

Comment: then build an fiddle and give us not only code fragments..

Comment: @FrankWisniewski updated my question with a code snippet!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [**`exportOptions`**](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-function.html). This is not so well documented, so you will have to dive into [`dataTables.buttons.js`](http://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.js) if you need more details. But basically you have a set of formatter callbacks for each section of the table :

```js
exportOptions: {
  format: {
    header: function( data, column ) {
      ...
    },
    footer: function( data, column ) {
      ...  
    },
    body: function( data, row, column, node ) {
      ...
    }
  }    
}
```

Use these callbacks to exclude markup or in other ways modify the content. I am not exactly sure what "*The exported pdf contains the tooltips text*" mean, but I guess you want to strip out the `.tooltipstext` `<span>`? `data` hold `<div class="tooltips">sr <span class="tooltipstext">Poistion</span></div>` so you can remove it with jQuery like this :

```js
{
  extend: 'pdfHtml5',
  title: 'My list',
  exportOptions: {
    format: {
      header: function ( data, column ) {
        return $(data).find('.tooltipstext').remove().end().text();
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Now the PDF column header will only contain `sr`.

It is more difficult to include glyphicons in the export. You will need to rebuild `vfs_fonts.js` and include `glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf`. Here is a guide how to do that

**https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/wiki/Custom-Fonts---client-side**

I have never tried that myself, so I cant say if there is any pitfalls